# How do I find a javascript value with Chrome developer tools?

Tags: javascript

Please bear with me, I'm not a programmer. There's a webpage that will show a javascript value when I do "inspect element" on it. Here's how it looks with chrome developer tools:

[image]

How do I find out how that `fingerprint` value is created with Chrome developer tools ? that value doesn't show up immediately, it shows up a few seconds after reloading the page. There's also this script right here if it's related somehow to the `fingerprint` value.

[image]

But opening that source link doesn't show the `fingerprint` value above, it just shows a bunch of javascript codes.

Comment: When I do that in the `Console` it shows this link https://h.online-metrix.net/fp/check.js?org_id=k8vif92e&session_id=paybuddy_id289qifon45netql7182bosse447

Comment: Provide www address please